# Получить значение Entry из функции класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Начал изучать Питона и столкнулся с проблемой
Есть код

```
class Main(tk.Frame):     
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
        self.db = db
        self.view_records()        
    def init_main(self):
        frame1 = tk.Frame(bg='light grey', padx=5, pady=5)
        frame1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.sumbank = ttk.Entry(frame1, width=13, font=("Arial Bold", 12))  # Ввод суммы
        self.sumbank.grid(row=1, column=1)
        but_calc = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Расчет", width="15", command=click_raschet)
        but_calc.bind('<Button-1>')
        but_calc.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10)

def click_raschet():
    sum_input = sumbank.get()
```

Строка `sumbank.get()` выдает ошибку "name 'sumbank' is not defined".
Уже всю голову сломал как ее победить! Как определить это имя?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, имя переменная определяется элементарно:

```
sumbank = 123
```

Но в данном случае это не поможет. Похоже, что у вас табуляция съехала и нужно всю функцию

```
def click_raschet():
    sum_input = sumbank.get()
```

сдвинуть вправо, чтобы она была внутри класса.

Comment: И `self` не забыть в нужные места вставить.

Answer (score 0):

Если `click_raschet` у вас отдельная функция вне класса `Main`, то нужно обращаться к `sumbank` как к атрибуту объекта класса `Main`, пример:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Main(tk.Frame):     
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
        # self.db = db
        # self.view_records()
    
    def init_main(self):
        frame1 = tk.Frame(bg='light grey', padx=5, pady=5)
        frame1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.sumbank = ttk.Entry(frame1, width=13, font=("Arial Bold", 12))  # Ввод суммы
        self.sumbank.grid(row=1, column=1)
        but_calc = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Расчет", width="15", command=click_raschet)
        but_calc.bind('<Button-1>')
        but_calc.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10)


def click_raschet():
    sum_input = main.sumbank.get()
    print(sum_input)


root = tk.Tk()
main = Main(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Либо сделайте `click_raschet` методом этого класса, тогда обращайтесь к атрибуту `sumbank` через `self`. Привязывать метод к кнопке тоже нужно через `self` (обратите внимание на комментарии `<-- self` в коде ниже):

```
class Main(tk.Frame):     
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
        # self.db = db
        # self.view_records()

    def init_main(self):
        frame1 = tk.Frame(bg='light grey', padx=5, pady=5)
        frame1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.sumbank = ttk.Entry(frame1, width=13, font=("Arial Bold", 12))  # Ввод суммы
        self.sumbank.grid(row=1, column=1)
        but_calc = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Расчет", width="15", command=self.click_raschet)  # <-- self
        but_calc.bind('<Button-1>')
        but_calc.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10)

    def click_raschet(self):  # <-- self
        sum_input = self.sumbank.get()  # <-- self
        print(sum_input)
```